# Change permissions on REST api?

Tags: rest-api

Specifically I'd like to allow Author roles to request this endpoint /wp-json/wp/v2/users?roles=author

Currently I get a 403 when trying.

I can't figure out a hook or some other method to customize what is and isn't allowed at a given endpoint.

Comment: if existing endpoints do not provide you wanted datas, it's better to create new one : https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/

Comment: That is pretty easy, but it strips out any user data so I can't do things based upon the user role.

Comment: what strips out data ? I just recommand you to create you own endpoint to retrive datas that you need.

Comment: Custom rest api routes don't have user data present from what I can tell.

Comment: custom endpoints return what you have develop then you can do everything you want.